# NVIDIA; Whea_Uncorrectable_Error

Tags: bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm running into some slight issues with Nvidia/GPUs.

It seems as though when I install the nvidia drivers or have them running, I experience a restart loop of WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR. The only way to get out of this loop and use my computer is via safemode.

I'm unable to install any debugging tools via safemode which means I'm unable to analyse my issue. If somebody could help out, I'd appreciated it.

I'm currently running an i7-5820K with a GA x99 Gaming 5 motherboard. I have two GALAX GTX 970s.

Around 10 minutes ago I installed a fresh version of windows technical preview. I'm running build 9879.

Here's the list of my minidumps since I installed the new OS and attempted to run after installing nvidia drivers: https://mega.co.nz/#F!pJFxRIaD!SJ0SN1cfE-lQB8Ht4532pQ

For clarification, I've tested this on multiple operating systems to the same result.

Comment: If this happens on a fresh installion of Windows then it's either a driber conflict with a beta version of windows or a hardware issue I suggest using a support version of a Windows that has SLI drivers...

Comment: This has happened on multiple versions. I've tested on Windows 8.1 and I've tested on windows technical preview 3 times today after reinstalling the os. I believe it is possible faulty GPUs, although I could do with more clarification.

Comment: You didn't mention that...Yes you have bad hardware

Comment: What would you recommend for checking what hardware is an issue? I recall when first building this computer it wouldn't boot, so I reinstalled ram sticks, ssds/hdds, GPUs, etc. and it booted. I don't believe it's solely the GPUs, is there anything I could run to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the dmp file, you have a L2 Cache issue (`GCACHEL2_ERR_ERR`) with your CPU:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffe000f0100028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000be200000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 00000000000b110a, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  rundll32.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
hal!HalBugCheckSystem
nt!WheaReportHwError
hal!HalpMcaReportError
hal!HalpMceHandlerCore
hal!HalpMceHandler
hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous
hal!HalHandleMcheck
nt!KxMcheckAbort
nt!KiMcheckAbort
0x0



FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE


===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffe000f0100028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d025afde00c838
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 1/1/2015 11:09:29 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe000f01000a8
Section       @ ffffe000f0100180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306f2
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000000

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe000f01000f0
Section       @ ffffe000f0100240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000000
CPU Id        : f2 06 03 00 00 08 10 00 - bf fb fe 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffe000f0100240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe000f0100138
Section       @ ffffe000f01002c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : GCACHEL2_ERR_ERR (Proc 0 Bank 19)
  Status      : 0xbe200000000b110a
```

I see that you use BIOS F6:

```
BiosVersion = F6
BiosReleaseDate = 09/09/2014
BaseBoardManufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
BaseBoardProduct = X99-Gaming 5
```

I see that there is a BIOS/UEFI version F7 available. Try this version. Also run CPU stress test tools like Prime95 to check if the CPU is damaged.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll be sure to stress test my cpu and update my bios. I'll run a memtest over the night, too.